# Local memory leak in constructor

Tags: c++

I was intrigued when one static code analysis software didn't complained about memory leak in constructor. Any inputs would be helpful. Be aware that, it's not class member. It's local pointer inside ctor

```
class ABC
{
    public:
        ABC()
        {
            int *p = new int[10];
            //No delete invoked...
        }
};
```

Comment: Time to look for a better static code analysis software? It's not clear what question you are asking.

Comment: So your question is really about this software whose name you haven't mentioned?

Comment: @remyabel not exactly. It was about the behaviour of constructor.

Comment: @deepdive Can you clarify? It sounds like the question is about why your tool is not detecting the memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need a static analysis tool for this. GCC has already ported [LLVM's sanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/index.html) and it's available as of GCC 4.9. It's also part of Clang too obviously.

> ✿´‿`) ~/test>  g++-trunk -fsanitize=undefined,address,leak -std=c++11
>   test.cpp -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
>
> ```
> test.cpp: In constructor ‘ABC::ABC()’:
> test.cpp:6:18: warning: unused variable ‘p’ [-Wunused-variable]
>              int *p = new int[10];
>               ^
> ```
>
> (✿´‿`) ~/test> ./a.out
>
> ```
> =================================================================
> ==1713==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks
>
> Direct leak of 40 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
>     #0 0x7f2535b07919 in operator new[](unsigned long) ../../../../trunk/libsanitizer/asan/asan_new_delete.cc:62
>     #1 0x4008cb in ABC::ABC() ~/test/test.cpp:6
>     #2 0x400856 in main ~/test/test.cpp:13
>     #3 0x31a1c21d64 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x31a1c21d64)
>
> SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 40 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
> ```

It's a runtime tool, but it works perfectly fine for situations like this. Of course, there's also always [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) but you're not going to be able to use the two together. Disable the sanitizer first before using valgrind. Last but not least, [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) is your friend.